# Running Multiple json objects through postman

Tags: java, json, rest, postman

I'm currently working on migration and have created around 15000 JSON objects in a `.json` file.

I want to save this into database through post request. I have an rest endpoint that takes list of JSON objects.

Is it possible to run them in a single request or should I write a script to chunk the 15000 JSON objects. Here is a example of 2 but I have 15000 different objects

```json
[
   {
      "_id":"6049efc887cda775a36bf71c",
      "age":39,
      "eyeColor":"blue",
      "name":"Padilla Bolton",
      "greeting":"Hello, Padilla Bolton! You have 4 unread messages.",
      "messages":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"6049efc887cda775a889bf71c",
      "age":39,
      "eyeColor":"white",
      "name":"Padilla",
      "greeting":"Hello, Padilla! You have 6 unread messages.",
      "messages":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the boby of resquest? you said `an rest endpoint that takes list of json objects` --> why just put all of that then sending the request?

Comment: Take a look at curl!

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void <List<Response>> create(@RequestBody List<Jsonrequest> requestDetails) {   }